# Why does ScreenOverlay show up in GEP, but not in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth-plugin

Simple KML layer for Google Earth Plugin, ScreenOverlay displays as expected (logo at lower right):

```
http://build.livegallup.com/community/trail-system/?tx_trailsystem_trailsystem[trail]=38&tx_trailsystem_trailsystem[trailSystem]=6&tx_trailsystem_trailsystem[action]=showearth&tx_trailsystem_trailsystem[controller]=Trail
```

Almost the same KML for Google Maps... no ScreenOverlay(???):

```
http://build.livegallup.com/community/trail-system/?tx_trailsystem_trailsystem[trail]=38&tx_trailsystem_trailsystem[trailSystem]=6&tx_trailsystem_trailsystem[action]=show&tx_trailsystem_trailsystem[controller]=Trail
```

Comment: This is pretty odd as it does work in maps like so: http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=http://build.livegallup.com/community/trail-system/trails/t/kml/dragons-tail-ramah/ramah-hogback-valley/xml/&ie=UTF8&om=1&ll=28.613459,-6.679687&spn=161.967701,360&z=2

Comment: There must be some thing funky in your implementation of the maps api at a guess, I will take a good look through for you...

Comment: I saw you took this down, did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: I'm into the same kind of issues, is there a way to enable logs in google maps in order to debug that kind of issues ?